# Retrieving Stripe Transfer Source Transactions

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am attempting to retrieve the latest Stripe transfers, with all their associated data - particularly their source transactions.

The request is working fine, but the `source_transaction` field is always null. My understanding of `source_transaction` is that it should return data tying the transfer to the card transactions that contributed the funds for that transfer. Such transactions were made, and are show on the Stripe Dashboard, but are not being returned via my request.

The request (sans all the error catching):

```
$stripe = new Stripe_Transfer();
$tmp = $stripe->all(["date"=>["gte"=>$_POST['dateFrom'], "lte"=>$_POST['dateTo']]],$c->stripe_secret_key);
```

A returned Transfer Object (to array):

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [apiKey] => abcd
        [values] => Array
            (
                [id] => tr_1234
                [object] => transfer
                [created] => 1434857809
                [date] => 1435017600
                [livemode] => 1
                [amount] => 5310
                [currency] => eur
                [reversed] => 
                [status] => paid
                [type] => bank_account
                [reversals] => Array
                    (
                        [apiKey] => abcd
                        [values] => Array
                            (
                                [object] => list
                                [total_count] => 0
                                [has_more] => 
                                [url] => /v1/transfers/tr_1234/reversals
                                [data] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [unsavedValues] => Array
                            (
                                [Stripe_Util_Set_elts] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [transientValues] => Array
                            (
                                [Stripe_Util_Set_elts] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [retrieveOptions] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [balance_transaction] => txn_5678
                [bank_account] => Array
                    (
                        [apiKey] => abcd
                        [values] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => ba_91011
                                [object] => bank_account
                                [last4] => 1234
                                [country] => IE
                                [currency] => eur
                                [status] => new
                                [fingerprint] => fghi
                                [routing_number] => ABCD
                                [bank_name] => MY BANK
                            )

                        [unsavedValues] => Array
                            (
                                [Stripe_Util_Set_elts] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [transientValues] => Array
                            (
                                [Stripe_Util_Set_elts] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [retrieveOptions] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [destination] => ba_91011
                [description] => STRIPE TRANSFER
                [failure_message] => 
                [failure_code] => 
                [amount_reversed] => 0
                [metadata] => Array
                    (
                        [apiKey] => abcd
                        [values] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [unsavedValues] => Array
                            (
                                [Stripe_Util_Set_elts] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [transientValues] => Array
                            (
                                [Stripe_Util_Set_elts] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [retrieveOptions] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    )

                [statement_descriptor] => 
                [recipient] => 
                [source_transaction] => 
                [application_fee] => 
            )

        [unsavedValues] => Array
            (
                [Stripe_Util_Set_elts] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [transientValues] => Array
            (
                [Stripe_Util_Set_elts] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [retrieveOptions] => Array
            (
            )

    )
```

As you can see, no source transactions. How do I get this data? Or why am I not getting it? I need to be able to tie money received in the bank with actual transactions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`source_transaction` is used for when you create a charge with a destination or you create a when you create a transfer and specify the the source_transaction.

To get all the charges included in one of the automatic bank account transfers you'd use the list balance transaction api [1]. Each time you create a charge a `balance_transaction` is created. This object represents the change to your stripe balance. They also have a transfer property. The list balance transaction api, lets you specify the transfer id, and it will return all balance transactions that were included in that transfer. From the balance_transaction you can then get the appropriate charge.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/api#balance_history

Comment: That's good to know! Thank you Matthew - I was despairing there for a while. Balance history it is.

Comment: Just to follow up, when I retrieve the balance history, the returned object does include a `sourced_transfers` key holding *some* information, but no actual related Charge details (this information *is* present when the balance is increased by a Charge, but not for banking transfers). It does contain a url parameter (`[url] => /v1/transfers?source_transaction=tr_abcd`) - is there not a way to get related Charge details for a banking Transfer?

Comment: you want to set transfer=tr_abcd

Comment: I did - I queried the balance history first (set type to transfer, and set some date params) and retrieved all the associated transfers (looks the same as querying the Transfers directly?) with their IDs. No actual sourced transactions. So I took those IDs, ran a loop and re-queried the balance history again with each ID set. Still no actual sourced_transfers. Really don't know where to go with this.

Comment: I'm confused why you want source transaction, to me it doesn't seem like you want that. You want the charge related to the balance transactions that a transfer has. So for the balance transactions returned by  transfer=tr_abcd, the balance transaction has a source property that should be an id of a charge

Comment: You are right - that is exactly what I want - I assumed that field held the data I needed. How then do I proceed? No method seems to give me any kind of Charge IDs. The source field contains a transfer ID, not a Charge ID

Comment: These are automatic transfers not manual (api created) transfers? The Balance history api should be returning multiple balance transactions

Comment: Yep, automatic, 7-day rollover banking transfers. I see on the API that that it shows a charge ID in that field, but this I assume is for money coming in and increasing the balance - not money flowing out in the form of a transfer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82024/discussion-between-matthew-arkin-and-eamonn).